# How get pvalue with a glmer model (lme4)

Tags: lme4-nlme

I am desperately looking a way to obtain the p-values for the fixed effects on my glmer model.
Any idea ??
I found a lot of things for lmer model but nothing worked with the glmer ...

thank all !

Comment: did you look at `?pvalues` in the `lme4` package?

Comment: yes, but all the solution are for lmer ...nothing work for glmer ...or I am too bad to make it run for glmer...

Comment: That's not true ... The second paragraph of `?pvalues` says "In the list below ... those marked (+) support GLMMs as well as LMMs"

Comment: Update your version of lme4? I'm working with generalised linear mixed models at the moment and the output of a glmer model built in lme4 gives p-values automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The `summary("model name")` function gives p values

e.g.,

```
model <- glmer(y ~ x + (1 | group), data = data, family = binomial)
summary(model)
```